# How to get dynamic id of an element to use in jquery on change event

Tags: jquery

I want to get the dynamic id of an element and implement change event for it, I have tried like this but this code doesn't work. How to get value of i here? **$(document).on('change', '#engravingOption_'+i, function () {**

This is html select element :

```
<select name="engravingOption[]" id="engravingOption_<?php echo $i ?>" class="engravingOptions" >
   <option value="No" <?php echo((isset($_SESSION['engravingOption']) && $_SESSION['engravingOption'][$i-1]=='No')?'selected="selected"':'');?>>No</option>
   <option value="Yes" <?php echo((isset($_SESSION['engravingOption']) && $_SESSION['engravingOption'][$i-1]=='Yes')?'selected="selected"':'');?>>Yes</option>
</select>
```

This is how clipboards are being adding, 1 clipboard always there on page load and then user can add more by clicking on add another button:

```
var active1 = true;
$('#add_another_clipboard').click(function (e) {
    if(!active1){
        return;
    }
    active1 = false;// handle to stop click listener until ajax success
    $('#clipboard_count').val(clipboardsCount);
    clipboardsCount+=1;
    var dataString = 'clipboardsCount='+clipboardsCount;
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "clipboard_option.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html)
        {
            $("#clipboard_option_inner").append(html);
            active1 = true; // activate it again !
            setEngravingFields();
        }
    });
});
function setEngravingFields(){
    for(var i=1; i <= clipboardsCount; i++){
        var e = $('#engravingOption_'+i);
        var value = e.val();
        if(value=='No'){
            $('#li_engraving_txt_'+i).hide();
            $('#engraving_txt_'+i).remove();
        }

    }
}

for(var i=1; i<= clipboardsCount; i++) {
 $(document).on('change', '#engravingOption_'+i, function () {
   var value = $("#engravingOption_"+i).val();
   var engraving_li ="<input type='text' id='engraving_txt_"+i+"' name='engraving_text[]' class='element text form-control' maxlength='20' placeholder='Engraving here (20 words)'  />";
   if (value == 'No') {
      $('#li_engraving_txt_'+i).hide();
      $('#engraving_txt_'+i).remove();
      $(engraving_li).remove();
   }
   else if (value == 'Yes') {
      $('#li_engraving_txt_'+i).show();
      $('#engraving_txt_'+i).show();
      $(engraving_li).insertBefore("#divcount_"+i);
   }
 });
}
```

Clipboards count variable:

```
var clipboardsCount=Number('<?php if(isset($_SESSION["clipboardsCount"])) echo $_SESSION["clipboardsCount"]?>');if(clipboardsCount == 0){clipboardsCount=1;}
```

Comment: what is "clipboardsCount"? please paste it

Comment: @Programmer21 var clipboardsCount=Number('<?php if(isset($_SESSION["clipboardsCount"])) echo $_SESSION["clipboardsCount"]?>');if(clipboardsCount == 0){clipboardsCount=1;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the change using universal selector

```
input[id*=common-part-of-your-id]
```

Here I used `input type="text"`. But you can use it with any other types like

```
input type="radio"
input type="checkbox"
```

See the working example

```js
//This function is simply to manipulate the dynamic html
//that you will be generating with your PHP code
var clipboardsCount = 3;
$(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < clipboardsCount; i++) {
    var select = $('<div class="dvBlock"><select name="engravingOption[]" id="engravingOption_' + i + '" class="engravingOptions" ><option value="No">No</option><option value="Yes">Yes</option></select><div style="display:none;" id="li_engraving_txt_' + i + '"><div id="divcount_' + i + '" >DisDv</div></div></div><br />');
    $('.container').append(select);
  }
});

//change event for existing/dynamically created select 
$(document).on('change', 'select.engravingOptions', function() {
  //extracting the index from id
  var index = $(this).attr('id').replace('engravingOption_', '');

  //getting the selected value of select
  var value = $(this).val();

  //input control to append
  var engraving_li = "<input type='text' id='engraving_txt_" + index + "' name='engraving_text[]' class='element text form-control' maxlength='20' placeholder='Engraving here (20 words)'  />";

  if (value == 'No') {
    $('#li_engraving_txt_' + index).hide();
    $('#engraving_txt_' + index).remove();
    $(engraving_li).remove();
  } else if (value == 'Yes') {
    $('#li_engraving_txt_' + index).show();
    $('#engraving_txt_' + index).show();

    //inserting the control, just before div(divcount_) corresponding
    //to selected section.
    $(engraving_li).insertBefore("#divcount_" + index);
  }
});
```

```css
.dvBlock {
  width: 350px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px 5px;
}

[id*="li_engraving_txt_"].element {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: I already tried using class .engravingOptions for select element but that insert the new element to all clipboards where option selected = yes. $(engraving_li).insertBefore("#divcount_"+i);

Comment: @Haroon . I've updated my answer, with more code. If this is not what you need, please add the sample html including li_engraving_txt_, divcount_ etc.

Comment: what that $(function()  is for?

Comment: li_engraving_txt_ is the div in which #engraving_txt_ along with other fields is being shown <div id="li_engraving_txt_<?php echo $add_number ?>" class="row">

Comment: $(function() is simply the document ready function, in which i have added code that will mock the dynamically created html using your PHP code. Could you please ;Run code snippet' and tell me, which part is not working as expected?

Comment: yes that works, I will accept your answer as it answers what i have asked, but I have one more issue should i ask here or post a new question?

Comment: Its up to you. I am not here for upvotes and scores. If you really feel that what u are going to ask, will contribute something to public, then make it as a new question. And if it will address only your problem,then u can ask it in here,

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript, unlike many other languages, scopes its variables to functions, not code blocks. In your case, you iterate over a variable `i` and append some asynchronous events to external elements during that loop. If you'd use `i` inside the loop for calculations etc, it would work properly and `i` would have a different value for each iteration.

Unfortunately, the event listeners you create can be called at any time, also after the loop has **finished iterating**. Therefore regardless of which element `change` event will ever be called, it will always use the **last possible value of `i`** (because that is the state in which `i` was left after the loop has finished, right?)

I think it will be easier to understand an example instead of a block of text:

https://jsfiddle.net/v7yo2qsk/

To prevent this behaviour of loop iterators, you have quite a few options. As in the example, you can call a **function** inside the loop, using `i` as a parameter. This will create a new function-scope, preserving the value of `i`, even for asynchronous events happening after the loop ends.

If you feel like going more fancy and modern-JavaScript, you may also consider using `let` and `const` instead of `var` - which are both block-scoped and a bit more predictable for programmers unfamiliar with closures.

For more, see:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Function_scope

Comment: if i use loop inside the function it works fine but that event I have to call on basis class which is same for all newly created elements and that does not work good for me :(